# Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'ParseClientConfiguration'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, heroku, parse-server

Migrating from Parse to Heroku. 
I've updated my AppDelegate.swift file to include:

```
let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {  
(ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in

ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "...";  
ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "...";  
ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "...";
```

My Podfile:

pod 'Parse', '1.11.0'

pod 'ParseUI'

pod 'Bolts'

pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '1.9.1'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

One solution online says to update Parse to the current version (1.12.0).

However Parse(1.12.0) and ParseFacebookUtilsV4(1.9.1) does not currently work together so I must stay at 1.11.0 for parse.
Ref: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseFacebookUtils-iOS/issues/35

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why would you not want to update ParseFacebookUtilsV4 along with the parse sdk? I haven't had any issue with version 1.11 with parse sdk 1.12.

Comment: You have no choice, `ParseClientConfiguration` was only introduced with v1.12.0 of the Parse SDK. Any older version won't really work unless you change the source code of the older version yourself. This is not recommended though as SDK updates can bring better performance, newer features and security fixes so you want to upgrade as often as possible.